# Cannot retrieve style using js

Tags: javascript, css, dhtml

```
<html>
<head>
<style>
#menu{
color :red;
}
</style>
</head>
<body>
<div id="menu">
ABCXTZ
</div>
</body>
<script>
a = document.getElementById('menu');
alert(a.style.color);
</script>
</html
```

What I retrieve is just an empty box.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To get the *computed* style you have to go a bit of a different route, like this:

```
var a = document.getElementById('menu');
if(document.defaultView && document.defaultView.getComputedStyle) {
    alert(document.defaultView.getComputedStyle(a, null).getPropertyValue("color"));
} else if(a.currentStyle) {
    alert(a.currentStyle.color);
}
```

[You can give it a try here](http://jsfiddle.net/nick_craver/rCZgG/2/), getting [`.style`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/STYLE) gets the properties defined on the element itself, not those inherited from the rules it matches.  The above uses the [`getComputedStyle()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/window.getComputedStyle) if available and in the case of IE, falls back to [`.currentStyle`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms535231.aspx).